# jquery mobile set selected value of a radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a radio button group like this:

```
   <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" name="optRestriction" id="optRestriction">
                <legend>Restriction</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="chkRestriction" id="chkRed" value="R" class="custom" />
                <label for="chkRed">Red</label>
                <input type="radio" name="chkRestriction" id="chkYello" value="Y" class="custom" />
                <label for="chkYello">Yellow</label>
                <input type="radio" name="chkRestriction" id="chkGreen" value="G"  class="custom" />
                <label for="chkGreen">
```

I am trying to set the selected value after retrieving values from the serve API.

I have tried various ways like below:

```
  $("input[name=chkRestriction][value=" + data.rows[0].restrictionCd + "]").prop('checked', true).trigger('change');

                                $("input[type='radio']:eq(" + data.rows[0].restrictionCd + ")").attr("checked", "checked");
                                $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");

                                $("input[name=chkRestriction][value=" + data.rows[0].restrictionCd + "]").prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
                                $('[name="chkRestriction"]').val([ data.rows[0].restrictionCd ]);
```

But none seem to work. A demo [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/2a0ju0ou/)

Appreciate any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set attribute "checked" and call refresh.

```
 $('input:radio[name="chkRestriction"]').filter('[value="R"]').attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/of7uvbwh/3/

Comment: it return error: *jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'*

Answer (score 0):

Set/unset the value of each radio button in a loop like this this:

```
var valToSet = myVal; // myVal is value to set from API

$('#optRestiction input').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this)
  if($this.val() == valToSet) {
    $this.prop('checked', true);
  }
  else {
    $this.prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

The 'changed' event fires when one of your inputs changes state.  Triggering it will accomplish nothing unless you have defined a handler for the 'changed' event for that input.

Comment: This does not appear to work, updated fiddle with your suggested changes https://jsfiddle.net/of7uvbwh/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

$('input:radio[name="chkRestriction"]').filter('[value="R"]').attr("checked",true).checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");